# Access Javascript JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I can't access to JSON object that exist inside another object , my code is like this:

```
var di = [ 
        { score: 0.75,
          obj:
           { _id: '8888888',
             title: 'diiiiiii',
             description: 'fdsf dfd sfjos sofjsof' } 
         },
        { score: 0.75,
          obj:
           { _id: '444444',
             title: 'dfssd ddd   ',
             description: 'sdfsfs', } 
         },
        { score: 0.75,
          obj:
           { _id: '55555',
             title: 'ffffood   ',
             description: 'iiiiiiiiii' } 
         } 
      ]; console.log(di.obj);
```

I get undifined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`di` is an *array*, not an object. You must use `di[0].obj` to get the first object, `di[1].obj` to get the second, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

of course not, its sitting inside an array. you gotta loop through it like this,

```
di.forEach(function(item)
{
    console.log(item.obj);
});
```